# Spring SockJS (over WebSockets) Message Ordering

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring SockJS (over WebSockets). My application requires messages from each client, to be processed in the same order as they were sent. Messages are processed in Spring using a thread pool, and this means that the order can be shuffled. I set the thread pool size to 1, and then message ordering was preserved.

The problem I have is that I can have many clients each of which requires guaranteed message ordering. If all the clients share the same thread then some clients are blocked due to lack of concurrency.

Is there was a way to have one thread dedicated to each client? Is there another way around this problem?

Comment: I worked around this issue by:

Comment: I worked around this issue by: Setting up one thread per session each thread containing its own java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue (which orders the messages); When messages arrive from Spring SockJS they are added to the sessions PriorityBlockingQueue; The sessions thread then takes the messages off the PriorityBlockingQueue and processes them. This solution although not ideal gave me the ordering and concurrency I required.